# How do I change one element change without affecting other elements with the same class?

Tags: jquery, html, class

```
<div class="hello 1">text</div>
<div class="hello 2">other text</div>
```

I am basically trying to make "text" color red when clicked if `$('.hello').hasClass('.1')` without making 'other text' red.

Comment: can you show us your javascript?

Comment: Better solution is to create another CSS class for "red color" and style your div with that as opposed to doing it inline. You can even do it runtime with JS by just adding/removing the newly-created class.

Answer (score 4):

Just select by both classes:

```
$(".hello.1").css("color", "red");
```

Note that the selector doesn't have a space before the second dot - if it did it would be looking for elements with the second class that are descendent of elements with the first.

Or if you're saying when a "hello" element is clicked you want to turn *that* element red only if it has the "1" class then:

```
$("hello").click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.hasClass("1"))
    $this.css("color", "red");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
.helloRed {
        color: red;
    }
```

JS:

```
$(".hello.1").addClass('helloRed');
$(".hello.1").removeClass('helloRed');
```

Answer (score 0):

this would also work:

```
$('.1').css('color', 'red');
```

but, as i'm sure you know,

## '1' is a terrible class name

```
$(function() {
 $('.hello').on('click', function() {
   $('.hello:eq(0)').css('color', 'red');

   $('.hello:first').css('color', 'red');

   $('.hello:first-child').css('color', 'red');

   $('.hello:not(:gt(0))').css('color', 'red');

   $('.hello:not(:last)').css('color', 'red');

   $('.hello:not(:not(:not(:not(.1)))):not(.2)').css('color', 'red');
 });
});
```

or to toggle the red:

css

```
.reddy-freddy {
  color: red;
}
```

js

```
$('.hello:first').click(function(){$(this).toggleClass('reddy-freddy')});
```